# How to let a part of a "background-image" still visible when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm recently facing a dilemma with my new Wordpress site.
I'm wondering how to keep a part of my header image visible when i'm scrolling down in the page.
For now, my header image is 75% of the page height, but when i'm scrolling down, the image disapear as it should be. 
But what i want, is that a certain part of it, let's say 20%, stay visible at the top in a "fixed" position.

So, to resume in pictures :

What i have without scrolling :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NxcQ.jpg

What i would like to have when scrolling down :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwoQw.png

I don't know if i'm clear enough, though, thanks to everyone who will try to help me on this !

Comment: Just to clarify, the 2nd image is only the very bottom portion of the top image?  Do you already have a background image placed on the html, body, or header elements?

Comment: The 2nd image is indeed the very bottom portion of the top image like you said and there is only a background image in the header. But John Koerner's solution was exactly what i needed, thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a jquery plugin like [sticky](https://github.com/garand/sticky):

```
<div class="top">Content</div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
   ....
</div>
```

Then for CSS, you apply your image:

```
.header
{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
    height:300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then in your js, you can use the sticky plugin:

```
$(".header").sticky({topSpacing:-250});
```

Notice the negative number on the spacing offset, which allows most of the image to be scrolled.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CZYav/2/

Answer (score 1):

I have a demo here: http://jsbin.com/ubolos/1/edit

Just keep tracking you scrolled distance and modify the `background` property of the `div` when you find that user has scroll too far down. No other plugins of jQuery needed.

Comment: This is a nice solution too, thanks, i like the kind of "parallax" effect.